# jquery chosen not showing data-palceholder message

Tags: javascript, webforms, jquery-chosen

I am using the pluginfrom http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ for my selects.
on document ready, i add an empty option to it and then call chosen, however it never renders the message defined in data-placeholder. what am i doing wrong? I am using asp.net webforms and the drop down is bound on the server.
below are both my markup and my javascript

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cbxLanguage" data-placeholder="choose a language..." CssClass="input-large chzn-select" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" runat="server" Width="210" required="Language required"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and my javascript that is being called on document ready:

```
function pimpSelect(select, options) {
            var prepend = '';
            if (select.attr('data-placeholder')) {
                prepend = '<option></option>';
            }
            if (options) {
                options = prepend + options;
                select.empty().html(options);
            }
            else {
                select.prepend(prepend);
            }
            if (select.hasClass('chzn-select')) {
                var _width = select.css('width');
               select.chosen({ width: _width });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

The reason is you should **initialize an empty valued option at first**.

```
<option value=""></option>
```

And your select should be like this.

```
<select name="cbxLanguage" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_cbxLanguage" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="choose a language..." required="Language required" style="width: 210px;">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">English</option>
  <option value="2">French</option>
  <option value="3">Spanish</option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure about the reason, but if you check `chosen.js` examples there you can find it.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/2wxz8/)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I did the following:

when you initialise the chosen field you have to not use % at width size.

```
$(".chosen").chosen({
    'no_results_text' :'Oops, nothing found!',
    'width'           :'700px',
    'search_contains' : true,
    'placeholder_text_multiple':'Please choose something ...',
    'display_selected_options':false             
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a server-side ASP.NET control. It's attributes do not (necessarily) translate one-to-one to the attributes which end up on client-side after render.

You need to do it in your code:

```
cbxLanguage.Attributes.Add("data-placeholder","choose a language...")
```

Comment: but i checked and saw that what ends up in my client code is actually
`<select data-placeholder="choose a language..." class="input-large chzn-select" style="width:210px" required="Language required">

Comment: Further information is needed. Include more code or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) with the non-working result

Comment: I know see what you mean. Try [contacting the author](http://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues)